# Best way to re-use data transformer logic in templates in Symfony

Tags: php, performance, symfony, inversion-of-control

I have a data transformer for forms to transform floats into a string that looks like a time or duration. For example, `165.3` in the database is transformed to `'2:45.3'` in my forms, and vice versa going back into the database. This works good for all of my forms, but I want the data to be presented in the string format in twig templates so users can see that something has a duration of `'2:45.3'` instead of `165.3`.

In order to do this, I extended twig to have a filter `secs2time`, and used the data transformer (rather than rewriting the same logic) in the twig extension to change the float into the string. It looks something like this:

```
public function secs2time($secs)
{
    return (new FloatToTimeTransformer)->transform($secs);
}
```

This works, but I get the feeling there is a better way. Is it bad to import and use `FloatToTimeTransformer` in my twig extension? Symfony transformers import at least two other classes (`DataTransformerInterface` & `TransformationFailedException`) that aren't needed in my twig extension. Will this hurt performance? What would be a better way?

I think this should be a common question, since you would almost never transform data to put into a database yet never show that data to users.

Comment: can you inject `FloatToTimeTransformer` using the constructor? One optimization could be to not instantiate every time that object

Comment: I think I can. But the way I have it, isn't the `FloatToTimeTransformer` only instantiated when secs2time is used?

Comment: Yes, only when `secs2time` is called, but every time it is called

Answer (score 0):

Your FloatToTimeTransformer transform method could call a static class method stocked in a TimeUtil class.
Then your twig extension could now call the same external static class method.

Note: this method should throw specific exception catched in your dataTransformer

### In a Model or Utils src directory

```
namespace \Model
use \DateTime

class TimeUtils
{
    public static secToTime($aFloat)
    {
        $time = "";
        ...// implements your transformation

        return $time;
    }

    public static timeToSec($aFloat)
    {
        $time = "";
        ...// implements your transformation

        return $time;
    }
}
```

### In your twig Extension

```
use Model\TimeUtils

...

public function secs2time($secs)
{
    return TimeUtils::secToTime($sec)
}
```

### In your dataTransformer

```
use Model\TimeUtils

...

public function transform($secs)
{
    try {

        return TimeUtils::secToTime($sec)
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function reverseTransform($time)
{
    try {
        return TimeUtils::timeToSec($time)
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```